# What food items can I take to USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

I am planning to take some dry fruits like dates, figs, and almonds, and also some mix for making masala chai, which I intend to give my host and  friends in the US. I have understood that there is a rather strict customs policy on bringing food items.

But it is customary where I come from (India) to give food to one's host when visiting. I feel it is impersonal to give duty free chocolates or alcohol.

What are the exact rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dried fruits in packages are not a problem.  Fresh fruits are prohibited.

If the masala chai is in a factory package it should be fine as well.  If it is home packed or from a fresh market, then USDA inspectors would have the final say.

Comment: What of dried fruits purchased from bazaar? For dates packages are fine. But for figs & almonds, its packed in the shop or atleast packed by the shop and sealed in unit sizes.

Comment: I would get the sealed packs.

Comment: also note the full list: http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/prohibited-and-restricted-items

Comment: @Vince Thank you. Thats what I was looking for.