# Why can't I take food from the plane when entering the US?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, regulations, british-airways

I was on a BA flight recently (LHR-JFK) and I was given a sealed cheese and tomato sandwich by a flight attendant about 90 minutes before landing. Everyone else was given a similar sandwich, probably as an afternoon snack. Because I was not hungry I kept the unopened sandwich on the empty seat next to me knowing that I would probably be hungry after immigration queues etc and I would eat it on the car ride into the city.

Just before the plane began its approach to JFK and the flight attendants were doing their last safety checks before landing, the same flight attendant told that I would be unable to take the sandwich from the plane and I would either have to eat it before disembarking or throw it into the bin! Not being hungry I left the sandwich behind.

**Why can't I take food off the plane?** Is this a USA thing or an international thing?

[This similar question does not answer my question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47848/what-food-items-can-i-take-to-usa)

Comment: I don't know for sure (thus can't answer) but I'd guess it has something to do with customs. The sandwich, containing a dairy product, probably came from the UK or somewhere outside of the US. Since you can't import dairy into the US, they probably don't let people take the sandwiches to avoid issues at customs.

Comment: Note that the airline itself doesn't really care if you take out the sandwich. They're just warning you about how US laws work. Otherwise you are free to put the sandwich in your jacket, eat it before immigration/customs and nobody would care.

Comment: When I came back from Germany they took all my chocolate covered kinder eggs.  Kids were bummed.

Comment: Actually, the linked-to question **does** answer your question. Contrary to popular belief, tomatoes are not vegetable but fruit. Fresh fruit is prohibited, so there you go (now of course there's "fresh" and there's "fresh" as on a sandwich... but what they really mean with "fresh" is "not dried, not heat-treated").

Comment: @JonH Kinder Eggs are actually banned due to a law from the 30s since they are candy containing non-food items.

Comment: @navigator_ - strange two years ago I brought an entire suitcase full of them.  Customs opened it, saw I had them and laughed about how good they were and let me have them.  So this is strange...

Comment: @Damon: tomatoes are very much vegetables. Vegetable is a culinary distinction, which has no relation to its biological classification. It's culinary a vegetable and botanically a fruit, both at the same time.

Comment: @JonH  You got lucky the first time then.  It is a stupid law.  Kinder Eier are awesome.  In general, you have to be careful about what you might have on you.  You cannot even bring back Curry packages that contain beef fat and broth in them from Japan because of the beef content.  All sorts of things you wouldn't know to think about.  Fresh items tend to fall on a list somewhere so I always eat all the fresh stuff before getting off the airplane.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The USA has restrictions on the import of food items. [Some information is given here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1272/~/food---general-food).

I have on one occasion forgotten items I bought before boarding, intending to snack on the flight. These were detected by a sniffer dog in the immigration queue and the items confiscated - I was not otherwise penalised, but I could have been fined.

In your case I guess that the tomato would have been the issue.

Comment: I think the US doesn't allow members of the public to import dairy products, either.

Comment: @DavidRicherby:  Most cheeses are acceptable for "personal use." From the [US CBP website:](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3619/kw/cheese)  "Solid cheese (hard or semi-soft, that does not contain meat) ... [is] not restricted. Feta cheese, Brie, Camembert, cheese in brine, Mozzarella and Buffalo Mozzarella are permissible. Cheese in liquid (such as cottage cheese or ricotta cheese) and cheese that pours like heavy cream are not admissible from countries affected by foot-and-mouth disease.  Cheese containing meat is not admissible depending on the country of origin."

Comment: ...  The real restrictions are on produce, eggs, and meat.

Comment: When I went to America I had to declare the one apple that I had with me and intended to eat after landing. Unfortunately it was confiscated.

Comment: I once realized right before US customs that I had a bag of roasted almonds in my backpack. I declared it, but they let me keep it.

Comment: @jkej your almonds were most likely [already from the US](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-california-almonds-20140112-story.html), and having been processed (roasted) would be unlikely able to grow any kind of invasive plant or harbor parasites. Tambre's apple on the other hand could have contained viable seeds, insects, or yeast cultures living on the skin. While the US might import the very same apples from the very same farm, the *official* import process is carefully regulated/documented to try and minimize the risks associated with bringing in foreign produce.

Comment: @tambre I brought an entire bag of apples with me to New York and they let me keep them. I guess YMMV. Might have something to do with the origin of your flight as well as they were grown and came from Canada.

Comment: Just wanted to add my personal experience as well. I brought some snacks in my luggage straight from Eastern Europe a couple of times when visiting the US. Technically they did contain small amount of dairy/eggs. On both occasions the customs ran them through a scanner once the border control gave clearance, and asked a couple of questions about the nature of the snacks and whether they were for personal use or selling. From my brief exchange with the customs officer it did seem that you absolutely must declare them on the questionnaire if you don't want to run into bigger problems, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert actually “most cheeses” contain meat (rennet) and are not permitted. It’s more likely to be a cheddar sandwich than brie.

Comment: @OrangeDog:  Interesting;  do you have a cite for that?  The [USDA Animal Product Manual](http://www.aphis.usda.gov/import_export/plants/manuals/ports/downloads/apm.pdf) seems to imply that rennet on its own is admissible for personal use (see Table A-1-16), so I'd be surprised if it was inadmissible as an ingredient in cheese. But as with many government practices, there may be arcane and counter-intuitive interpretations involved.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert if that’s not what it’s referring too, what ungodly cheese does have meat in it then?

Comment: @OrangeDog [Head cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_cheese) is pretty ungodly.

Comment: @OrangeDog I would assume [Casu Marzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casu_marzu). I'm not aware of any other cheeses with meat in them, but it's possible.

Answer (score 17):

The airline is required by US law to follow a pretty complex set of rules relating to [international garbage](https://www.nbaa.org/ops/environment/20110302-international-trash.php) in order to prevent pests from entering the US. Many airports have [incinerators](http://journaltimes.com/news/local/batten-airport-makes-money-with-flight-trash-incineration/article_10ce7b1c-4594-11e0-a836-001cc4c002e0.html) on-site to comply with USDA requirements, and it's the responsibility of the crew to collect the trash so it can be destroyed.

They're not going to account for every edible item on the plane, especially prepackaged candies and snacks, and if you stuff the thing in your bag, they aren't going to start searching the plane for it. But if they see you with something that needs to be disposed of, they will want to ensure the regulations are complied with and dispose of it properly.

Specifically, you can refer to [9 CFR 94.5(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/9/94.5). To simplify (and, you know, consult a lawyer or something if you need legal advice on garbage for your airline), regulated garbage includes all "meals and other food that were available for consumption by passengers and crew on an aircraft but were not consumed" from international flights (except: Canada is excluded and Hawaii included). If you've got regulated garbage on your plane, it "may not be disposed of, placed on, or removed from" the plane unless it is disposed of properly (in this case, that's a fancy way of saying "very expensively"), in a way that ensures it won't introduce agricultural pests and disease. This even applies to [leaving food on the plane for the return flight.](http://www.ntcbffa.org/docs/DFW08-005Amended/airplane.pdf) "Passenger takes the food home and eats it later" is, sadly, not listed as an approved form of disposal.

So as I read the regulations, the crew was following the required procedure to ensure that all regulated garbage was collected for proper disposal.

Answer (score 8):

While the other answers raise some good points, I think it is important to point out that technically the flight attendant is wrong. You *are* allowed to bring food into the USA, as long as you **declare** it to customs, and as long as it is not on the list of forbidden food products (which can change rapidly, for example in response to specific diseases/health hazards).

Many (most?) passengers do not declare any food. Bringing an undeclared sandwich can indeed result in fines and other unpleasant consequences. So, the flight attendant is giving some simplified advice to help you avoid these consequences. Declaring food (even food that is allowed) may delay your passage through customs, and may sometimes result in bags being opened, increased questioning, etc, so probably not worth it for a sandwich.

However, I often travel with lots of other food that I'm going to declare anyways. In situations like this, I've always just included food that I'm taking from the plane in my declaration, and never had any issues with it. The worst that can happen is that they'll throw it away.

Comment: "Declaring food (even food that is allowed) may delay your passage through customs" - one time (in New Zealand) I got through customs faster by declaring food, because then I didn't have to go through the line to have my baggage scanned to make sure I wasn't *not* declaring food.

Comment: @immibis, shhhh! that tactic is known by few! (I did it yesterday).

Answer (score 1):

djna is correct but not complete and it is very country specific "The USA (...)".

To answer your last question: no, it is a general rule, that you are not permitted to bring sandwiches outside airplane (so not just US stuffs), for few reasons:

- custom: food (also animals and plants) is very regulated in all countries, mostly because of possible disease (to agricultural sector).
- sanitary consideration: plane food is carefully controlled, safe and keep in cold, before to serve it to you, but after some hours on air temperature, the food could not be edible, and if you will have some problem, you will blame the airline.  You should also consider that the food was not prepared on the airplane, so it is "relatively" old, so after is warmed up, it should be relatively eaten quickly.

For chocolates and snacks, usually the airlines are less severe. Such food is prepared (heated and sealed) so it should not be a concern for both the above points. Customs could not agree, but still safe to eat before you pass the custom. [tomatoes and cheese cannot be disinfected with heat]

Comment: Airline food (especially a sandwich!) isn't going to become dangerous to eat within a few hours of being in your bag. And, even if it did, I really doubt that customs and immigration authorities would care that you might blame the airline if you ate it and got sick. Also, chocolate and many kinds of snacks can't be sterilized by heating.

Comment: I don't know. I would not eat them, also on normal shops (I mix cheese and vegetable late in case of hiking). Sandwiches are stored in refrigerators, for a reason. You will find billions of bacteria on cheese, many thousand in tomatoes and salad (and mixing.. bad), and nearly none in snacks. It is not 100% sterilized, but just count the bacteria. Then think about fecal bacteria and other nasty bacteria. Preparation of tomatoes, cheese and sandwich requires much manual work and non sterile environment. Check also custom rules, on some countries they distinguish them.

Comment: So you're prepared to eat a cheese sandwich on a hike after carrying it in your pack for a few hours, but not prepared to eat a cheese sandwich after carrying it off a plane? Sorry, but that makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: But it is so. Check food preparation best practices. Entire tomatoes can be stored for weeks, cheese for more time. Just preparing and combining has additional problems (check biology for the reason, or you taste, if it is not health, it is the taste that is bad). You see it also at McDonalds: hamburgers are trashed after few hours, but not the original ingredients used to make them. On food industry there are many "after doing this you should consider food as that" (or "expiry date is that")

Comment: @DavidRicherby The original question did not say that Customs prohibited the sandwich, but that the airline did. While customs may not care about a lawsuit against the airline, the airline absolutely does. Also, the specific number of hours before the sandwich is eaten, and how and where it is stored cannot be known. Giacomo is also correct about prepared foods having shorter lifespans than the ingredients themselves.

Comment: @alephzero The USA is no more paranoid about this than a great many other countries. And your stereotyping really isn't helpful.

Comment: Actually, I hear that the airline accepts no liability for passenger illness resulting from inflight food consumed after disembarking the flight.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the EU, UAE, Australia, and USA all have a total ban on personal travellers carrying non-manufactured (i.e. Raw Agricultural) foods, including Dairy. The most serious offenses can result in jail time of up to 10 years! Also, if it has been proved that the Airline supplied the food, then they can also get into serious trouble with CBP.